# Using a string to pass to adaptor instead of a string

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to pass a string from `Mainactivity` to the `databaseadapter` class to update the column one with a `string` (as its designated with `string` instead of `int`) in `sqlite` but realize that `db.update()` only works with `int`.

a) In mainactivity, for int

```
Integer jacky = 78;
myDb.updateK(jacky);
```

b) In mainactivity, for String

```
String jackie = "jacko";
myDb.updateK(jackie);
```

In databaseadapter

```
String cup = "_id = 1";
//since jack doesn't have to be jacky or jackie, and can be mary
public void updateK(int mary){              
ContentValues tree = new ContentValues();
tree.put("columnone", mary);
db.update("TableOne", tree, cup, null);  
}
```

In the case above, only case a) works when using an int whereas case b) using a string jacko, does not work. Is there a way to work around this and pass the string from `mainactivity` to `databaseadapter`?

As you probably can tell, I'm new to android and I appreciate any pointers you guys can give me.

Comment: Why are you calling `myDb.updateK(jackie);` because your method defined only accepts int `public void updateK(int mary){ `?

Comment: I know. How do I use string for the myDb.updateK() instead of an int?

Comment: Check my answer I have not tested it, but let me if it works

Comment: So the change is to make it public void updateK(Object mary){ } instead of updateK(int mary). Thanks. I will try it later once I get back.

Comment: Yes , also the int has to be replaced with Integer class `Integer jacky = 78;` and remember to cast before extracting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) In mainactivity, for int

```
Integer jacky = 78;
myDb.updateK(jacky);
```

b) In mainactivity, for String

```
String jackie = "jacko";
myDb.updateK(jackie);
```

In databaseadapter

```
String cup = "_id = 1";
//since jack doesn't have to be jacky or jackie, and can be mary
public void updateK(Object mary){   
ContentValues tree = new ContentValues();
tree.put("columnone", mary);
db.update("TableOne", tree, cup, null);  
}
```

NOTE : Your tree should also accept objects

Answer (score 1):

`"columnone"` should be a column name of table `"TableOne"`. Verify the type of that column (you should define column data type when define your table). According to your question it should be a `INTEGER` type. If so you can change its type to TEXT then you have to change the case a) as follows.

```
myDb.updateK(String.valueof(jacky));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would pass the int jacky (i.e. 78). What I'm looking for is to pass the String jackie (i.e. jacko) into the updateK method.

Comment: Then change the updatePK to accept String and always pass a string value while calling. If you have the int jacky, then pass String.valueof(jacky) to the new method. If you have string jacko, then just pass it as is.

Comment: Change its argument type from int to Object